# Do class and race abilities count against your at-will/encounter powers?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

At first level, you know 2 at wills, 1 encounter, and 1 daily power.

Let's say I'm a Tiefling Wizard.

I have an racial power of "Infernal Wrath" which is an encounter power. Wizards can also learn Burning Hands, Chill Strike, Force Orb, Icy Terrain, and Ray of Enfeeblement.

Does this mean I can only use one of the six? Or can I use Infernal Wrath, and another of the five for the class?

Similarly, there are 4 cantrips, and 5 at will spells. I get 2 at-will powers at first level, so does that mean I get the 4 cantrips and 2 of the 5? Or only 2 of the total 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

The limitation on power choices comes from within the class and is only applicable to choices offered by the class.

A tiefling wizard will get their racial power for free and cannot take cantrips as first level powers outside of the class feature because they are described as "Wizard Utility" without a level. Only class features may grant powers without a level on the power.

Beyond the racial power, the cantrips, they also get 2 "wizard at-will 1's" , learn 2 "wizard  encounter 1's" and 2 "wizard daily 1's." Of the two encounters and two dailies offered by the wizard class, they can prepare one each, as per the rules of the wizard spellbook.

Comment: So the bottom line is... I get the cantrips and 2 more at wills, I get two of the encounters, and I have to prepare one of them, forgoing the other for the day, two dailies, one of which must be prepared, the forgone for the day, AND I get my Tiefling racial without needing to prepare it?

Comment: @Total - correct.

Comment: Awesome. I thought it would be silly to give someone 4 powers in one category, and 5 in another, and only let them pick 2 of the 9. Thanks!