# Do racial powers stack with class powers?

Tags: dnd-4e

I have just started learning to play D&D 4th edition.

I have chosen an elf ranger as my starting character, it says they have a racial power: elven accuracy. Does this power count as another encounter power or is it a bonus to the other 2? Would you then have 3 have 3 encounter powers or is it one normal encounter attack and the elven accuracy?

Comment: @Luke please read [our FAQ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq).  RPG.SE is for expert Q&A on RPGs - not for asking people to post a whole rulebook for you piece by piece.  All your questions would not be questions if you owned and had read the 4e rulebook.  Please do so, and then ask specific questions on items that are still confusing after you've done some basic thinking about them.

Comment: As a referencing note, the question is quite similar in content to [Do class and race abilities count against your at-will/encounter powers?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8270/do-class-and-race-abilities-count-against-your-at-will-encounter-powers?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

**Racial powers are seperate from class powers. You get them in addition to your class powers.**

As an elvish archer, you should have:

- 2 at will class attack powers:

  - Twin Strike (usable every round)
  - Nimble Strike (usable every round, to round out the need for twin strike)
- 1 at-will class non-attack power

  - Hunter's Quarry (usable every round, allows you to designate someone who is deserving of extra damage)
- 1 encounter class attack power

  - Two-Fanged Strike (usable once per encounter, delicious extra damage)
- 1 racial encounter power

  - Elven Accuracy (mmm, rerolls. Once per encounter)
- 1 daily racial power

  - Skirmishing Stance (once per day, get a buff for the entire encounter when you move.)

As you can see, the different sources of actions stack. Your class combines with your race (and theme if you're using them and magic items) to give you a menu of actions that you may choose from every turn at varying frequencies.